# Convert Variable to global in the class . . .php?

Tags: php, class, variables, global

I need to send $user to inside the class and render function to make it global variable.

because it not work unless i write "$user" in the class and render function.

Please help me.

```
$user = 'admin';

class Template{
public function render($template_name)
{
    global $user;
    $path = $template_name . '.html';
    if (file_exists($path))
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($path);

        function if_condition($matches)
        {
            $parts = explode(" ", $matches[0]);

            $parts[0] = '<?PHP if(';
            $parts[1] = '$' .$parts[1]; // $page
            $parts[2] = ' ' . '==' . ' ';
            $parts[3] = '"' . substr($parts[3], 0, -1) . '"'; //home
            $allparts = $parts[0].$parts[1].$parts[2].$parts[3].') { ?>';
            return $allparts.$gvar;
        }

        $contents = preg_replace_callback("/\[if (.*?)\]/", "if_condition", $contents);
        $contents = preg_replace("/\[endif\]/", "<?PHP } ?>", $contents);   

        eval(' ?>' . $contents . '<?PHP ');
    }
}

 }

 $template = new Template;
 $template->render('test3');
```

Comment: Why not just create a constructor where you set the variable?

Comment: Basically, see Alma Do Mundos answer

Answer (score 2):

**Never, never use global variables**

They are awful, they bind your code to context and they are side-effect - if you'll change your variable somewhere in 2054-th line of 119-th included file, the behavior of your application will change and then good luck with debugging that.

Instead you should either pass your user in method's parameters:

```
public function render($template_name, $user)
```

or create property in class instance:

```
class Template
{
   protected $user = null;

   public function render($template_name)
   {
     //access to $this->user instead of $user
   }
   //...
}
```

-and, of course, initialize `$user` property in class [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).